# Can't write the "}" character on IntelliJ IEDA 16.1

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10

On the latest version of `IntelliJ IDEA` (16.1.2), I can't write the `}` 
character :(

I'm on Windows 10 Pro. When I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> on a `source code file`, IntelliJ IDEA don't write any character!

It's strange because I don't have any problem to write the opposite character: `{`.

The trouble is so strange because I can write the `}` character in the configuration search field of the editor.

I don't use "special" configuration or keymap, only few plugin like Scala, PHP, Symfony...

Note: I don't have any problem on other editor like Sublime Text 3

Thanks you for your help.

Jimy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching under the keymap options, I have find the solution at my problem.

The `Default`'s IntelliJ IDEA 16 keymap have 2 shortcuts keys who causing the troubles on source editor :

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad =</kbd>

To fix the problem, on the keymap editor, navigate to `Main menu` > `Code` > `Folding` > `Expand Recursively` and remove the two assignments as you can see in the screen shot bellow.

[image: keymap shortcuts]